# How to share cookies between subdomains?

Tags: apex, visualforce, cookies

We are using cookies on our force.com site which is under domain support.example.com but we have other non-force.com applications on another subdomain i.e. search.example.com.

How can I define the cookie on the force.com site to the example.com domain (top level domain) so that both subdomains can have access to read/write the cookie? Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how you save your cookies, but this reference shows how it's possible using PHP; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458090/cross-subdomain-cookie-handling-for-session

Comment: Thanks @Lex. We are using the force.com cookie functionality https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm#apex_classes_sites_cookie

Comment: As far as I understand from the documentation what you want doesn't seem to be possible. Maybe you can add a page to your Site that offers the cookies to the caller (although I can imagine this would expose security issues).